# Show the latest post titles for posts using a specific category

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I want to get the latest post titles for posts using a specific category, in Drupal 6.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drupal shows those nodes in http://example.com/taxonomy/term/$tid. If all you want is getting a page listing the nodes using a taxonomy term, that is the page to look at.

If you want to obtain the list of nodes using a taxonomy term with code, you can use the following one, based on [taxonomy_select_nodes()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_select_nodes/6).

```
function mymodule_get_node_titles($tid, $order = 'n.sticky DESC, n.created DESC', $limit = 10) {
  $term = taxonomy_get_term($tid);
  $tree = taxonomy_get_tree($term->vid, $tid, -1);
  $descendant_tids[] = array_merge(array($tid), array_map('_taxonomy_get_tid_from_term', $tree));

  $args = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $descendant_tids);
  $placeholders = db_placeholders($args, 'int');
  $sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT(n.nid), n.title, n.created FROM {node} n INNER JOIN {term_node} tn ON n.vid = tn.vid WHERE tn.tid IN (' . $placeholders . ') AND n.status = 1 ORDER BY ' . $order;

  $sql = db_rewrite_sql($sql);

  return db_query_range($sql, $args, 0, $limit);
}
```

The code to call that function is similar to the following one.

```
$result = mymodule_get_node_titles($tid);
$items = array();
while ($row = db_fetch_object($result)) {
  $items[$row->nid] = $row->title;
}
```

`$tid` is the taxonomy term ID.